# Any idea how i can versioning my graphql API?

Tags: laravel-lighthouse

In rest API , we could version our APIS like this :

> example.com/api/v1/

And what is the idea when using a single GraphQL endpoint ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The short version is: You don't :)

The long version is best explained by the [GraphQL site](https://graphql.org):

> While there's nothing that prevents a GraphQL service from being versioned just like any other REST API, GraphQL takes a strong opinion on avoiding versioning by providing the tools for the continuous evolution of a GraphQL schema.
>
> Why do most APIs version? When there's limited control over the data that's returned from an API endpoint, any change can be considered a breaking change, and breaking changes require a new version. If adding new features to an API requires a new version, then a tradeoff emerges between releasing often and having many incremental versions versus the understandability and maintainability of the API.
>
> In contrast, GraphQL only returns the data that's explicitly requested, so new capabilities can be added via new types and new fields on those types without creating a breaking change. This has led to a common practice of always avoiding breaking changes and serving a versionless API.

Source: https://graphql.org/learn/best-practices/#versioning

Comment: Depends on the use case.  Shopify has a fantastic GQL implementation and they use versioning.  The tradition GQL stance is to use evolution instead of versioning but it's not black & white.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like that

```
services.AddGraphQLServer("v1").AddQueryType<QueryV1>();
services.AddGraphQLServer("v2").AddQueryType<QueryV2>();
                

 app.UseEndpoints(e =>
            {   
                e.MapGraphQL("/graphql/v1","v1");
                e.MapGraphQL("/graphql/v2","v2");
             
            });
```

Comment: Although not very clear from the OP's question this is tagged for Laravel Lighthouse which is a PHP GraphQL server and from the looks of you code it's TS or C# which is not very helpful in this context since we are dealing with a PHP GraphQL server.

Answer (score 0):

As per Graphql Documentation

GraphQL only returns the data that's explicitly requested, so new capabilities can be added via new types and new fields on those types without creating a breaking change. This has led to a common practice of always avoiding breaking changes and serving a versionless API.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).